# Northeast Conference on Science and Skepticism - 29 JUN to 2 JUL 17

Tags: discussion, conference, skepticism

Sorry I am remiss in posting this. [I will be at NECSS again this year.](https://necss.org/) I am presenting a workshop, and I will be working the conference. I'd love to see some of you there.

Answer (score 5):

Please join me in congratulating Larian for speaking at such and important event, alongside major skeptical figures like Randi, Novella, etc.

Larian's workshop:

[image]

Workshop 1B - Steve Lundquist - If You Look Outside the Right Side of the Aircraft: Still Not a UFO